# javascript getters and setters for all children in object

Tags: javascript, object

My `getter/setter` function is

```
var o={}
var bValue = {};
Object.defineProperty(o, 'b', {
    get: function() { return bValue; },
    set: function(newValue) {func(); bValue = newValue; },
});

function func()
{
    console.log(o)
}
```

So if I define `o.b={msg:"hello"}` it will call the function `func()`.

But what I want is after this if I define `o.b.msg="new"` I want to trigger `func()`.
I tried a for loop but it's not working, it's showing "max stack exeeded" error.

How to do this for all objects in `o` with pure JavaScript?

Comment: The stack error occurs because you try to set 'b' again within the setter. This causes a infinite loop of getting and setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To call `func()` on setting new value to child of `o.b` you need to do:

```js
var o={};
var children = ['b' /* some known o properties */]

children.forEach(function(child) {
    var childValue = {};
    Object.defineProperty(o, child, {
        get: function() { return childValue; },
        set: function(newValue) {
            func();

            Object.keys(newValue).forEach(function(key) {
                var value = newValue[key];
                Object.defineProperty(childValue, key, {
                    get: function() { return value },
                    set: function(newValue) {
                        func();
                        value = newValue;
                    }
                })
            });
        }
    });
});
function func()
{
    console.log(o)
}
```

As you can see you can do it only if your know property names of `o` object beforehand (see `children` variable). If you want to create a getter for undefined property of `o` object - then this is not possible at this time. If you can use `ECMAScript6`, then you can realize it through `Proxy` object (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)). But otherwise it's not possible in javascript at this time.

Comment: You can also use `Object.observe`.

Comment: @torazaburo Year, good suggestion. But right now only v8 engine (Chrome, NodeJS, etc) supports `Object.observe` (see [here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es7/#Object.observe)). And as it is just ECMAScript7 proposal, it will take long time before we can use it in browser.